# How to unzip downloaded file in Git bash

Tags: unzip

```
$ unzip /c/Users/David/Downloads/initializer-verekia-4.0
unzip:  cannot find or open /c/Users/David/Downloads/initializer-verekia-4.0, /c/Users/anusa/Downloads/initializer-verekia-4.0.zip or /c/Users/David/Downloads/initializer-verekia-4.0.ZIP.
```

my git version(2.36.1) windows

Comment: $ unzip /c/Users/David/Downloads/initializer-verekia-4.0.zip Try adding the file extension

Comment: Git-bash is a port of bash provided *with* Git (because Git requires a POSIX-compatible shell for Git to be able to work). It is not part *of* Git and is not a Git command. So this is not a Git question, it's just a question about using this particular command line interpreter on your computer.

Comment: The error message is clear: `cannot find or open` so you have 2 options, the file doesn't exist or you don't have read permissions. Check with `ll /c/Users/David/Downloads/initializer-verekia-4.0.zip`